# Firebase update function performs recursively

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am making a website of where people can upload memes but I'm currently stuck at updating likes of meme
Here's the code
Js

```
function like(id) {

  firebase.database().ref("memes/" + id).on("value", (snap) => {

    const cs = snap.val().likes || [{
      name: ""
    }]

    let res = [...cs, JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"))].filter(item => item)

    console.log(res)

    firebase.database().ref("memes/" + id).update({
      likes: res,
    });
  })
}
```

html

```
<p><button onclick="like('${y.name}/${y.head}')"><ion-icon name="thumbs-up"></ion-icon></button><b>${1 || y.likes.length }</b></p>
```

Problem is when I click on button the like function performs like recursively and just keeps adding objects in like field which is array in RealTime database .

Like this:

```
likes:
0-> object
1-> object
....
```

Comment: Replacing the on() with once() in 2nd line of your JS will do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are opening a listener to `memes/{id}/` with the code:

`firebase.database().ref("memes/" + id).on("value",(snap) => {`

So every time you update you get another callback and that's why it keeps recursivelly adding items.

You can replace it with `once` and that should solve your problem.

Reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#section-reading-once

Explanation for the on value:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#value

> The value event is used to read a static snapshot of the contents at a given database path, as they existed at the time of the read event. It is triggered once with the initial data and again every time the data changes.

Comment: My anxiety got deletd